# How can I get the last Query's run time with Sqlsrv?

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm using PHP 5 and the sqlsrv database driver. I'm setting a QueryTimeout of 15 seconds because I'm hitting a lot of different servers repeatedly, and if I hit a timeout once I need to stop the operation and hit the next server.

Currently I'm just using a variable to track the start time and end time and aborting if it's `>=` my QueryTimeout, but is there any way to get the *actual* query time out of the sqlsrv driver itself? I didn't see anything that looked like it would help in the [list of sqlsrv functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sqlsrv.php). I'd like to be able to get the time of the last query rather than wrapping each query in variables that grab the current time.

Comment: Are you worried about a query timeout or connection timeout? Or both?

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark since I'm not familiar with SQL Server, T-SQL, `sqlsrv`, etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx

Seems like you can `SELECT last_elapsed_time FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats`

Comment: That's another hit to the (local) database though...not a huge problem, but I was hoping the sqlsrv driver had some way I could just get the last run time with a function/object somewhere.

Comment: It doesn't look like `sqlsrv` does but `PDO` might.  Have you looked into that?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but my framework supports it, I'll see if it has such a function

Answer (score 0):

you may use this:

```
DECLARE @start_time DATETIME, @end_time DATETIME
SET @start_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

sql code here

SET @end_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
SELECT DATEDIFF(ms, @start_time, @end_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this at the start of your query:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
```

When you view the output results, they will include timing statistics.
e.g.

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
    CPU time = 47 ms,  elapsed time = 109 ms.
```

Edit: you must set sqlsrv to not return warnings as errors with this command:

```
sqlsrv_configure('WarningsReturnAsErrors', false);
```

The statistics text is returned in sqlsrv_errors()